# Select all and none on items list , in knockoutjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I am trying to implement a list of items that each have a checkbox to select the item. On top of the list, there is 2 radio button to check all or none items. However, when I update the selected list, the checkbox is not checked. I have got a fiddle here to illustrate the problem:
http://jsfiddle.net/hawaii/VcZBf/2/

Could you guys help me on this please.

Thanks

Comment: Why this, weird... `viewModel.checkedPeople (new Array());`

Comment: my bad, I was just did it unintentionally with my JavaScript intellisense

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED**
So you want to do a "checkAll(On this Page)" implementation.

To maintain changes to your checks from one paging event to the next, I would push the currently checked items in the grid to the server during the paging event, or have the act of checking / unchecking maintain back to the DB right after each event.  Its a cheap call, and you aren't at a risk of losing checked items because the user hit the [backspace key accidentally.](http://www.vilepickle.com/blog/2010/11/18/0090-disabling-backspace-key-page-jquery)

**Without sending the checks to the server on every paging operation...**

- your checks to be stored locally separate from the list even when the template that those records represent is paged to another page.
  (make sure to only update the people observablearray when you get your next page)
- then, importantly, on every page event you need to apply the checks back onto the grid for the shown items.
- Finally, to aleviate the fact that the checkmarks arent representing their checked state (you click check-all, and you don't see them get checked).  This is because you had `checked:$parent.checkedPeople`. which will never work, since checkedPeople is an array, not a boolean.  I changed this to a function that asks if this person ID is in the checked People array

anyhow.. here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/VcZBf/24/

Its a rough concept.

**WITH sending the current checks to the server on every paging operation**

- Each object now would have an "isChecked" observable.
- On every paging event, the current page's checkmarks are persisted to the DB server side.
- Then if you page back to a page with checkmarks on it, they show back up for you.

Much smoother.

reference from previous answer:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment

Comment: gmail check all is what I really like to implement, check all will allow me to select all items on the page first, then it will display a message saying if I want to select all items on my mailbox

Comment: Hello Brandon, thanks for the effort, it is a very promising solution. However, I decided to go with kogrid, where I can do my own custom template to achieve what I want.

Comment: I did initially recommend that.  But then changed my answer to accomodate for your desire to do the gmail-esque check-all scripts.  If this answer led you to a solution, I would be greatful if you could mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

I [simplified](http://jsfiddle.net/5fAtz/3/) your structure a little bit.  I don't think having both `people` and `checkedPeople` was really knockout-y.  If you do want checkedPeople, it can probably just be a read-only computed observable.

I added an `IsChecked` field to the initial people (all false).  I then changed the checkboxes to map to that.  Finally, I had the radio buttons change all IsChecked fields using `arrayForEach`.

Right now, the radio button GUI isn't really intuitive.  You can take two appraoches:

1. Make them regular buttons (recommended)
2. Make them check and uncheck automatically by data-binding the checked to a computed `allChecked` flag in the model.  This would mean they check automatically even if you check the boxes one by one.

I also took out your logging.  I'm assuming that was debugging, but you can re-add it if needed.

Comment: Hello there, thanks for your help, however, the problem is that I am doing server side paging on this and I need to allow the user to select all items ( which are more than just the people on client side), therefore I am holding the checked people in a id array)